# Read payload from redirected URL in vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, redirect, endpoint

I need to read the form data in payload of redirected URL which has content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I am not sure how I can do this in vuejs.
My url is http://nw.localhost:3032/home/cybs which has x-www-form-urlencoded form data as below

```
TransactionId: qY610uAHb6xkSgTDwRj0 
MD: cybschallengesuccess
```

[image]

I tried to use `this.$route` but it does not fetch x-www-form-urlencoded form data from the redirected URL.
is it possible to read the form data from a URL?